# Bootstrap Modal only appearing on Chrome etc. when debugging, but working fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

We have a 'Loading' modal in our application that is called by a `showWaitDialog()` method shown below:

```
var waitDialogOptions = {
  show: true,
  keyboard: false
};

function showWaitDialog(context) {
  context = context || "Loading";
  $('#main-wait-dialog .wait-context').text(context);
  $('#main-wait-dialog').modal(waitDialogOptions);
  console.log("SHOW MODAL");
}

function hideWaitDialog() {
  $('#main-wait-dialog').modal('hide');
  console.log("HIDE MODAL");
}
```

We're experiencing a problem where the modal is not displaying in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera etc. despite the `showWaitDialog()` method being called. The only browser the modal appears in when running normally is Firefox. The method is definitely being invoked as the `SHOW MODAL` message is appearing in the browser console in each case.

When we step through our javascript however using a browser debugger in any of the browsers exhibiting the problem, the modal is behaving normally when we step over the `showWaitDialog()` method. The modal only displays in these browsers if the javascript execution is paused.

The HTML in the JSP for the modal is as follows:

```
<div id="main-wait-dialog" class="wait-dialog modalDialog" class="modal fade narrow-modal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1>
                                <span class="wait-context">Loading</span>, please wait
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active"
                                            style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                                            <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- .col-* -->
                            </div><!-- .row -->
                        </div><!-- .modal-body -->
                    </fieldset>
                </div><!-- .modal-content -->
            </div><!-- .modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- .col-* -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .wait-dialog -->
```

Why is this occurring? What can we do to make our modal behave as expected? Any help would be appreciated.

Further details can be provided if necessary.

**EDIT:** If it helps, an example of how these methods above are called is:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {

  showWaitDialog('Loading users');

  // do something, eg. an ajax call

  hideWaitDialog();

}
```

Comment: What is the value of context in chrome? Is it any different to the value in Firefox?

Comment: when and how is `showWaitDialog` triggered, by click or on load?

Comment: @oserk - It varies, most of the time it is directly after or a few methods down the call stack from a click event, but in some instances it is called from the `beforeSend` function of `jQuery.ajax()`

Comment: @DanielCooke - I may be having a stupid moment but I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @mnnalxndr in the function showWaitDialog(context) - what is the value of the context parameter in both Chrome and firefox?

Comment: @DanielCooke - Oy, I'm an idiot. I didn't know whether you meant browsing context or something.

No, there's no difference. All that's passed in for `context` is a string that's inserted into the text on the modal. So, if you want the modal to say 'Loading users, please wait' instead of the defaing 'Loading, please wait', you'd just pass 'Loading users' as the `context` argument. It shouldn't have an effect on whether the modal is displayed or not.